# Residuals vs Fitted Interpretation and Comparison

Tags: data-visualization, residuals, fitting

[image: Old Model]
[image: New Model]

Hello these are both Residuals vs Fitted plots I have created for my models. The top is the plot for an old model, and the bottom is the plot for an improved new model. What is the difference between the two graphs? What improvements can be tell from the differences? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the plot a bit more?  What is the red curve?  Should this have a "self-study" label?

Comment: The red curves are the lowest fit of the plots.

Comment: What are these data? What is "RSSI"? There are pretty clear stripes in the data.